# OpenLayers won't load without double click in PhoneGap/jQuery Mobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, openlayers

I'm having trouble trying to integrate a basic OL map with an Open Street Map layer into a multi-page jQuery Mobile HTML interface - it can find the map 'div', and loads almost everything properly, but the control has to be clicked before the map tiles load. Here's the map code:

```
var map, layer;
function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map');
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 12
        );
}
```

This function is called using the 'ondeviceready' event that fires when PhoneGap is ready to accept commands. This is the page that contains the map:

```
<!-- page showing map of route being recorded. -->
<div id="route" data-role="page">
    <div data-id="recRoute" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-id="recRouteFoot" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there some way I could get the map/layer to be redrawn when the page is loaded into the DOM? I would rather a user not have to click the map controls to actually see the map.

UPDATE: the 'pageinit' handler for the 'route' page:

```
/** Executes when gps page loads. **/
$('#route').live('pageinit', function(event){
        $('.del').detach().trigger('create');
        /** Executes when addTag button clicked. **/
        $('#createTag').click(createTag);
        /** Executes when getPic button clicked. **/
        $('#getPic').click(function() {
                getPic();
        });
        /** Executes when pauseResume button clicked. **/
        $('.pauseResume').click(function() {
                pauseCounter();
        });
        /** Executes when stop button clicked. **/
        $('.stop').click(function() {
                stopCounter();
        });
        // remove stupid button.
        $('#del').detach().trigger('create');
        // load map.
        init();
        $('#map').trigger('create');
        $('#route').addClass('ui-page-active').trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: I should also mention that the page containing the map is not the first page in the application to be loaded.

Comment: It seems double clicking the map element all together also makes the map appear.

Comment: I have tried giving the map element focus by using the '.focus()' function, and none of jQuery Mobile's built-in refreshing functions work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the map only when the «#route» page is initialised, so when it has dimension.

Take a look at the `pageinit` event in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: I've used that event in my app to add button handlers and make UI handlers, so I put my init() call at the end. It works as in the map now appears, but now the 'route' page is the first page to appear. I thought it might be because I'm calling a trigger function before it so I placed it before that. I've placed the code for my event handler within the question.

Comment: Placing the init call before the trigger took me back to the double click requirement. I experimented with some alert statements and it seems nothing is called in the init after the map is created or the event handler after init is called.

Comment: `$('#map').trigger('create');
$('#route').addClass('ui-page-active').trigger('create');` Why do you need to do that?

Comment: The first command was an attempt to refresh the map element (that failed and upon removal doesn't change the situation), and the second command makes the element in question appear active - it's left over from another problem that was later solved. - In other words neither are needed anymore.

Comment: Ok, I've worked out why nothing is run after the map is created. I ran a try/catch statement on the function call, and it gives the following error: 'TypeError: 'null' is not an object'. I did some searching and after running the script through firebug in Firefox, I think I've got the same problem as documented here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3385 - if I dismiss the dialog, I can still access the map after double clicking it still.